# IBM ILOG CPLEX IDE: File <path> Not Found

Tags: cplex, ibm-ilog-opl

I reinstalled cplex after some time and tried to run a simple script.
This error keeps appearing and I don't understand why, it doesn't matter what I write in the code of the script, Ilog cplex ide can't seem to find the project folder. Other than the reinstallation I did not make any other use of it.
[image]

Project is the name of the OPL project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is delete the project from within the IDE and then reimport the project in the IDE.

[image]